# Using synchronous JAX in registration form for checking username availability

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, synchronous

I have a registration form. When I hit the Submit button it should check if the Username is not taken and that the passwords match. So I wrote a few functions: one that checks the passwords, one that checks if the username is available and the main function, that calls for the 2 checking functions. The password checking function works nice, but my problem is with the username checking function. This is the function:

```
function checkIsUsernameExist(){
    if($("#txtNewUsername").val() == "") {
        $("#divIsUsernameExist").html("");
        return false;
    } else {
    $.getJSON("inc/API.php", 
        {
            command : 'isUsernameExist',
            username : $("#txtNewUsername").val(),
        },
        function(result)
        {
            if (result != true){
                $("#divIsUsernameExist").html("This username is available!");
                return true;
            } else {
                $("#divIsUsernameExist").html("This username is not available!");
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When the username is empty, it does return False. But when some value is entered it returns Undefined.
Somebody told I should use Synchronous JAX (but didn't tell me how), so I tried to write this code:

```
function checkIsUsernameExistAsync(){
    if($("#txtNewUsername").val() == "") {
        $("#divIsUsernameExist").html("");
        return false;
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'inc/API.php',
            data: ({
            command : 'isUsernameExist',
            username : $("#txtNewUsername").val(),
            cache: false,
            async: false
            }),
    success: function(result){
        if (result != true){
                $("#divIsUsernameExist").html("This username is available!");
                return true;
            } else {
                $("#divIsUsernameExist").html("This username is not available!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    }
}
```

But I get the same result - False when it's empty, Undefined when some value is entered. I tried to change `$.ajax`to `$.getJSON` in the second function, but still had the same result.

This is the code from API.php:

```
case "isUsernameExist":
        echo (isUsernameExist($_REQUEST["username"]));
        break;
```

it calls for a function in included page BusinessLogic.php, here's this function:

```
function isUsernameExist($username)
{
    $arr = select("select * from users where username='$username'");
    if(count($arr) == 1)
    return json_encode(true);
    else
    return json_encode(false);
}
```

How can I make it work??

Thank you!

Comment: SQL injection *cough* ..

Comment: @Rob Huh? What does SQL injection has to do with what I asked?

Comment: @lgal It's not the cause of the problem, but your application is vulnerable, because you don't escape the `$username` variable. As for the question itself, and the "solution": You've placed `async` and `cache` at the wrong place (currently, they're a part of `data`). Also, the `return` statements in the `success` handler do not give a return value to your function. You have to avoid sync AJAX, and properly implement a callback method.

Comment: @ Rob W, why he should avoid AJAX??? he can use it and check if the username exist or not. 
@Rob W are u sure that the server return a result to the client script?

Comment: @PalAla Not AJAX, but synchronous AJAX. That blocks the user's UI until a response has been received. I'm sure that the server returns the correct response, unless the code does not match. Have a look at the `else`-block with the `$.ajax` implementation: There's no `return` inside it, so it's not a surprise that the function returns either `false` (if)` and `undefined` (else).

Comment: @RobW Sorry, I'm a newbie, dealing with this only for a few weeks now... Let's just say for now that vulnerability isn't my main issue right now, for now I just want to make this code work. I tried to rewrite it like this `...data: ({
   command : 'isUsernameExist',
   username : $("#txtNewUsername").val()
   
  }), cache: false,
   async: false,
  success...` but still have the same result. Sorry, I'm clueless regarding all the rest, where and how should I implement the `return` or what's the proper way to implement the callback here...

Comment: @lgal How is your JavaScript `checkIsUsernameExistAsync` function called?

Comment: @RobW When the user hits the submit button button, it activates `register()` function, which calls for `checkIsUsernameExistAsync` like this: `function register() {
  var userName = checkIsUsernameExistAsync();
  var passwordMatch = checkPasswordMatch();
  alert("Username = " + userName);
  if(userName && passwordMatch){
  $.getJSON("inc/API.php",
   {... (rest of the registration code)` The alert here is just temporary, to see what I get when the function is executed.

Comment: @lgal Change it to something like `function register(){function(){checkIsUserNameExistsAsync(function(userName){ ... rest of code...});};`, and add a callback method to the `checkUserNameExistsAsync` method.

Comment: @RobW Sorry, I'm really confused now... I thought that `success : function(result)` is the callback method. And I didn't really understand how to work with the `register()` function you wrote. Do you think you can show it to me here, please? [http://jsfiddle.net/wGfzc/](http://jsfiddle.net/wGfzc/)

Comment: @lgal A quick write-up: http://jsfiddle.net/wGfzc/1/.

Comment: @RobW Well, almost there - now I get False every time. I tried to change it back to `(result != true)`, but then I got False only when it was empty (which is OK), but True whether the username does exist or not.

Comment: @lgal Remove `async:true`, and add `dataType: 'json'` http://jsfiddle.net/wGfzc/2/

Comment: @RobW You're a magician! :) Well, it worked! I still changed it to `result != true`, because BusinessLogic.php returns True if the username does exist. So in this code, if it's not True, than Username is available, and the callback will be true. It works! :) I wish you could write it as an answer and not as comment, so I could vote you up, or mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarise the comment chain:

- Avoid synchronous AJAX requests: Remove `async: false`
- Add `dataType: 'json',
- `return` inside a `success` handler of `jQuery.ajax` does not set the return value of the outer function. To correctly pass the results, define a callback handler. Replace:
- Before: http://jsfiddle.net/wGfzc/
- After: http://jsfiddle.net/wGfzc/2/